# segmentation fault when returning pointer in functions

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include "dfsbfs.h"
#include "graph_list.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void initQueue(queue* q)
{
        q=(queue*)malloc(sizeof(q));
        q->first=NULL;
        q->rear=NULL;
}

void enqueue(queue* q, vertex* v)
{
        if(isQEmpty(q))
        {
                q->first=v;
                q->rear=v;
        }
        else
        {
                q->rear->nextV=v;
                q->rear=v;
        }
}


vertex* dequeue(queue* q)
{
        printf("enter");
        if(isQEmpty(q))
        {
                fputs("error dequeue", stderr);
                exit(-1);
        }
        else
        {
                vertex* returnNode=q->first;
                q->first=q->first->nextV;
                printf("dequeue???");
                return returnNode;
        }
}

int isQEmpty(queue* q)
{
        return q->first==NULL;
}

void bfs(graph_list* graph, name startVertex)
{
        queue q;
        initQueue(&q);
        vertex *v;

        graph->verticies[startVertex].color=GRAY;
        graph->verticies[startVertex].distance=0;
        graph->verticies[startVertex].parent=NULL;
        printf("ffffffff");
        printf("bbbbbbbbb");
        printf("aaaaaaaa");

        visitVertex(&(graph->verticies[startVertex]));
        enqueue(&q, &(graph->verticies[startVertex]));

        while(!isQEmpty(&q))
        {
                v=dequeue(&q);     //SEG FAULT HERE
        /*
                node* current=v->next;

                while(current!=NULL)
                {
                       graph->verticies[current->nodeName].color=GRAY;
                        graph->verticies[current->nodeName].distance=(v->distance)+1;
                        graph->verticies[current->nodeName].parent=v;

                        visitVertex(&(graph->verticies[current->nodeName]));

                        enqueue(&q, &(graph->verticies[current->nodeName]));
                }

                v->color=BLACK;
                */
        }

}


void visitVertex(vertex* v)
{
        printf("Visited Vertex: %c \n", (v->vertexName)+65);
        printf("hello");
}
```

From this code, I am getting 'segmentation fault' in the code:
`v=dequeue(&q);`

If I write `dequeue(&q);` not `v=dequeue(&q);` , there is no error.

But, I don't know why latter gives me an error. The pointer variable `returnNode` has `q->frist`'s address. So, after returning, v should have `q->frist`'s address.

But why this gives me segmentation fault?

Comment: Add a `main` function so we can compile and test your code. Did you try running it under `valgrind` or a similar memory overflow checker?

Comment: That's classic.`malloc(sizeof(q))` allocates a size of a *pointer* not a queue...

Comment: Are you sure about this `return q->first==NULL;` ?

Comment: Look up the hundreds of other questions about this (lists, trees, queues — all run into this problem).  `initQueue` has multiple problems — not allocating enough space and not getting the information about what it allocated back to the calling code (so leaking memory).  You have to change the interface to `initQueue()`.  If that's not possible, then the function can't allocate the memory usefully.

Comment: `void initQueue(queue* q){ q=(queue*)malloc(sizeof(q));...` does not change the value of `q` passed in from the caller.  **C is pass-by-value**.

Comment: Plus the classic(?) passing the address of an instance of `queue` into `initQueue()` which allocates a new (wrong-size) bit of memory whose address is thrown away, leaving the original `queue` object (inside `bfs()`) uninitialised.

Answer (score 3):

Your `initQueue` is wrong. There's no need to allocate a `queue` as you are passing in a pointer to a `queue` instance, you just need to initialize the variable. It should be something like this:

```
void initQueue(queue* q)
{
    q->first=NULL;
    q->rear=NULL;
}
```

NOTE: Although you don't need it, the call to `malloc` was wrong. Saying `malloc(sizeof(q)` will allocate something the size of a pointer as that's what `q` is. You should have said `malloc(sizeof(queue)` at that's the thing you wanted to allocate.